# MailItem.Save exception for IMAP account, "The operation cannot be performed because the message has been changed"

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

This exception occurs for IMAP account if I'm going to save mailitem in Outlook addin. 
This occurs when I change user properties of the previous messages in the chain while forwarding/replying mail.

I've gone through this https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_win10-mso_2016/the-operation-cannot-be-performed-because-the/ba4fa59e-0813-4874-b122-10bcf6e586af?page=1 and tried the solutions of @Vijay_Verma but it doesn't work for me.

Here is my code:

```
 private void DraftItems_ItemAdd(object Item)
    {
        try
        {
            Outlook.MailItem mailItem = Item as Outlook.MailItem;

            Outlook.UserProperty mailUserProperty = mailItem.UserProperties?.Find("ABC");

            Outlook.Folder mailItemfolder = mailItem.Parent as Outlook.Folder;

            string emailId = mailItemfolder.Store.DisplayName;

            List<string> entryIdsInConvn = GetEmailsInConversation(mailItem.ConversationID, emailId);

            if (entryIdsInConvn != null && entryIdsInConvn.Count > 0)
            {
                Outlook.Folder inboxFolder = null;
                Outlook.NameSpace nameSpace = null;

                if (mailItemfolder != null)
                {
                    nameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
                    inboxFolder = mailItemfolder.Store.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox) as Outlook.Folder;

                    foreach (string entryId in entryIdsInConvn)
                    {
                        Outlook.MailItem mi = null;
                        try
                        {
                            mi = nameSpace.GetItemFromID(entryId, inboxFolder.StoreID) as Outlook.MailItem;
                            if (mi != null)
                            {
                                AddUserProperty(mi, mailUserProperty.Value);
                            }
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            if (mi != null)
                                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mi);
                        }
                    }
                    if (inboxFolder != null)
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(inboxFolder);
                    if (nameSpace != null)
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(nameSpace);
                }
            }

            if (mailUserProperty != null)
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mailUserProperty);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }
    }

    public void AddUserProperty(Outlook.MailItem mailItem, string Id)
    {
        Outlook.UserProperties mailUserProperties = null;
        Outlook.UserProperty mailUserProperty = null;

        try
        {
            mailUserProperties = mailItem.UserProperties;
            mailUserProperty = mailUserProperties.Find("ABC");

            if (null == mailUserProperty)
            {
                mailUserProperty = mailUserProperties.Add("ABC", Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText, false, 1);
            }

            mailUserProperty.Value = Id;
            mailItem.Save(); //Exception here
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             //The operation cannot be performed because the message has been changed
        }
        finally
        {
            if (mailUserProperty != null)
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mailUserProperty);
            }

            if (mailUserProperties != null)
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mailUserProperties);
            }
        }
    }
```

here I'm replying on mail, then adding user property and saving it and on DraftItemAdd event, adding user properties to other mails in conversation.

Can someone tell me what can be cause of this exception?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please can you post your code and the exception you are getting so we can try to help you

Comment: Where and when do you try to save the item? Do you run the Save operation on the main thread?

Comment: Thanks @TomHalson I've posted the code

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev here I'm replying on mail -> adding user property -> saving it -> on DraftsItemAdd event, adding user property to its parent mail (i.e., mail in same conversation) and then at the time of MailItem.Save() I got this exception. Yes its in main thread. Thanks!

Comment: after catching this exception try reading some property then save like
var s=mail.Subject; mail.Save();